# MySQL Join table row based on lowest cell value

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables in a MySQL database like this:

PRODUCT:

```
product_id | product_name
-----------+-------------
1          |  shirt
2          |  pants
3          |  socks
```

PRODUCT_SUPPLIER: (id is primary key)

```
id  |  supplier_id  |  product_id  |  part_no  |  cost
----+---------------+--------------+-----------+--------
1   |  1            |  1           | s1p1      | 5.00
2   |  1            |  2           | s1p2      | 15.00
3   |  1            |  3           | s1p3      | 25.00
4   |  2            |  1           | s2p1      | 50.00
5   |  2            |  2           | s2p2      | 10.00
6   |  2            |  3           | s2p3      | 5.00
```

My goal is a query that joins the tables and outputs a single row for each product joined with all fields from the corresponding supplier row with the lowest cost like this:

```
product_id | product_name  | supplier_id   |  part_no   | cost
-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+---------
1          | shirt         | 1             |  s1p1      | 5.00
2          | pants         | 2             |  s2p2      | 10.00
3          | socks         | 2             |  s3p3      | 5.00
```

At present I do have the following query written which seems to work but I'd like to know from any of the more experienced SQL users if there is a cleaner, more efficient or otherwise better solution?  Or if there is anything essentially wrong with the code I have?

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, s. supplier_id, s.part_no, s.cost
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_supplier s ON
   (s.id = (SELECT s2.id 
            FROM product_supplier s2
            WHERE s2.product_id = p.product_id
            ORDER BY s2.cost LIMIT 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run:

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, s.supplier_id, s.part_no, s.cost
  from product p
  join product_supplier s
    on p.product_id = s.product_id
  join (select product_id, min(cost) as min_cost
          from product_supplier
         group by product_id) v
    on s.product_id = v.product_id
   and s.cost = v.min_cost
```

I don't see the point in an outer join. Is every product is on the product_supplier table? If not then the outer join makes sense (change the join to inline view aliased as v above to a left join if that is the case).

The above may run a little faster than your query because the subquery is not running for each row. Your current subquery is dependent and relative to each row of product.

If you want to eliminate ties and don't care about doing so arbitrarily you can add a random number to the end of the results, put the query into an inline view, and then select the lowest/highest/etc. random number for each group. Here is an example:

```
select product_id, product_name, supplier_id, part_no, cost, min(rnd)
  from (select p.product_id,
               p.product_name,
               s.supplier_id,
               s.part_no,
               s.cost,
               rand() as rnd
          from product p
          join product_supplier s
            on p.product_id = s.product_id
          join (select product_id, min(cost) as min_cost
                 from product_supplier
                group by product_id) v
            on s.product_id = v.product_id
           and s.cost = v.min_cost) x
 group by product_id, product_name, supplier_id, part_no, cost
```

If for some reason you don't want the random # to come back in output, you can put the whole query above into an inline view, and select all columns but the random # from it.

Comment: thanks.. this is exactly the kind of input i was hoping for.  I'm still learning sql and the syntax of the second join (inline view?) is something entirely new for me.  i appreciate the nudge.

Comment: and yes, in theory, every product should have at least one corresponding supplier row - though in reality it's hard to say if that will always be the case

Comment: A subquery in the from clause is referred to as a few things, 'inline view' is a term typically used by people working with oracle, some will also call it a 'sub-select' or 'derived table' or just as a subquery. Basically if you were to run that query on its own (the one I've aliased as v) you would get the lowest cost for each product, putting that query into an inline view as part of a larger query allows you to join to it, ie. limiting the rows to those where the cost is equal to the lowest cost for the given item.

Comment: Using "join" will result in any product with no suppliers to be eliminated. If you use "left join" (in the direction of product to product_supplier) they won't be eliminated.

Comment: The problem with this query I've found is that it can return more than one row if two suppliers have identical costs - whereas mine always returns exactly one row.  In the case where costs are identical I don't mind if the choice is arbitrary - but the important thing is that the resulting part no matches the supplier id.

Comment: @billynoah you can still eliminate ties without using a correlated subquery, see edit

Comment: thanks - it's funny the more i dig in to this it seems like a very common question but i've yet to find an answer here on stack overflow that has mega upvotes.  i'm assuming somewhere there is a very thorough discussion of this.  if anyone knows please post a link.